# List products including out of stock products in custom module (without listing out of stock products on the whole shop!)

Tags: magento2, product, collection, repository

I’m having a custom route in a custom module where I’d like to list a subset of products for a specific search criteria. I’d like to include here just for this action the out of stock products.
BUT I don’t want to show out of stock products on the whole shop generally so this config option is not the way to go.

In my custom view model I got something like the following to query products.

`$products = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);`

This does work fine and the returned product list matches my search criteria but it doesn’t include the out of stock ones which also would match the criteria.

Is there a way to include them without using the production collection directly?

It seems pretty odd that the framework here always excludes the out of stock ones due to a plugin on the collections `load` function.

I thought about adding another collection processor to the ProductRepository but I can't manage to do it.

In the end the only thing to do would be `$collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);` which disables the plugin behavior excluding the out of stock products.